# Traverse array value getting from api in php

Tags: php, api

I am trying to traverse array value getting from api. In postman I an sending data like

```
   key              Value  
item_id_array[]     [7,1]
```

I have used x-www-form-urlencoded to send data from api. After that when I am trying to traverse value like

```
$item_id_array = $request->get('item_id_array');
dd($item_id_array );

//output shows
 array:1 [
 0 => "[7,1]"
 ]
```

But I want it like

```
array:1 [
  0 => 7
  1 => 1
]
```

I am using laravel 5.6 and **post** method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[]` from `item_id_array[]` in Postman?

Comment: yes . It also give **"[7,1]"**

Comment: Then try `item_id_array[]` with 7 and 1 separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to send an array in a http request to be parsed by PHP is by sending the array items individually as follows:

```
?item_id_array[]=1&item_id_array[]=7
```

In postman, you just have to send both items with the same key

```
key                 Value  
item_id_array[]     7
item_id_array[]     1
```